# Arca-Swiss Z1 SP quick set options

Tags: tripod, ball-head

I'm considering Arca-Swiss Z1 SP but I don't fully understand different options for quick release mechanism. There are three different options:

- MonoballFix
- FlipLock
- Classic

So far my understanding is that MonoballFix requires different plates than other two. I would like to have a clamp compatible with broad range of release plates and L-Brackets. Especially Kirk and Wimberley. So which one is more suitable for that requirement? MonoballFix or one of other two?

I also found this confusing note about FlipLock and Classic on my favorite retailer's website:

*Please note: the safety-stop feature of the Wimberley plates do not work with the new "double decker" Arca Swiss quick release clamps on the Z1 head. The Wimberley plates can still be used, but users must ensure that the clamp itself is sufficiently tight as the safety pins in the end of the Wimberley plate will not prevent it from slipping out.*

The side question would be: Is there any difference in Z1+ (not yet available from my retailer)? Is it worth waiting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three QR's are Classic knob, Fliplock and monobalfix type.
The Fliplock is a quick and sturdy QR. But it is designed for our plates or a single manufacturer's plates only.  many of the other manufacturers, while making 'Arca-Swiss style' Qr's and plates, did not copy the specifications and so some are wider and a few are even narrower than our plates. So if you buy a mixture of manufacturers plates, you do not want the fliplock.
The Classic QR will accept almost all of the Arca-Swiss style plates made and also will accept the new compact series of monobalfix plates in a dual channel design.  The knob is captive so won't unscrew and is extremely rugged and sturdy.  The Fliplock will also accept the compact monobalfix plates as well.
The monobalfix system will accept only the monbalfix plates and is very compact and makes the head a bit lighter as well.  These plates are very compact, as is the QR and rigid as well.  Totally centered the compact plates will also pan perfectly if pano stitching is in your bag of tricks.
We make L brackets and pano kits for both series of QRs as well.
Hope this helps.
Rod Klukas
Arca-Swiss USA
Representative

Comment: Thanks. I watched few videos on youtube and came to the same conclusion - Classic is what I need. The only question is, how to get old classic clamp without compatiblity for noarrow plates as I really don't like this double decker design.

Comment: Welcome to [photo.se]! We welcome company representatives providing product support here, but you  might want to look at [this help article](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/product-support) for more information on how to support products on Stack Exchange. Thank you for your contribution, and we hope to see you here again!